# Next element of the list prediction

Tags: neural-networks

I want to make a prediction which element will be next in the list. 
To make an example, on a certain date certain number appears, so I have a list of {date, number} elements. I wanted to use Predict function in Mathematica (I use 10.4) using a truncated version of the list I have to train it, i.e.

```
Predict[{
 {{date1, number1}} -> {date2, number2},
 {{{date1, number1},{date2, number2}} -> {date3, number3},
...}]
```

but I got an error saying that the lists cannot be used as input.

Could anyone suggest a way to use the next date/number prediction based on the given list of such elements?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html). The list needs to be of the form `{date1 -> number1, date2 -> number2...}` or `{date1, date2, ...} -> {number1, number2, ...}`

Comment: I need the prediction on the whole element {date, number}, not just number for the given date

Comment: `Predict` can only deal with scalar outputs. A neural network can handle non-scalar outputs. It will need a custom encoder to deal with `{date, number}` inputs, and a way to ensure that the predicted output always has valid dates. It also requires all inputs to have the same dimensions so the example above with input `{{date1, number1}, {date2, number2}}` will not work. Inputs of that form will need another neural network that can handle it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to create such a neural network with built-in Mathematica functions, or it is easier to write everything from scratch?

Comment: It can be done with built-in functions, at least in version 11.3, not sure about 10.4. Using a very crude encoding of the input date/number like `data = {{2018, 10, 1, 1} -> {2018, 10, 2, 2}, {2018, 10, 3, 
    3} -> {2018, 10, 4, 4}, {2018, 10, 5, 5} -> {2018, 10, 6, 6}}`. Then the simplest network `net = NetChain[{16, 4}, "Input" -> 4, "Output" -> 4]`. Train it `trained = NetTrain[net, data]`. Use it to predict `trained[{2018, 10, 6, 6}] // Round`, gives `{2018, 10, 7, 7}`

Comment: Thank you, Rahit. I have a question though. In yor case you predict one lelement based on one previous elemet. Is it possible to use built-in functions to train neural network so that it predicts one new element from the list (of any number of elements) of the lements of the same type?
I.e. I want to train network on something like
{{date1,number1}}->{date2,number2},
{{date1,number1},{date2,number2}}->{date3,number3},
{{date1,number1},{date2,number2},{date3,number3}}->{date4,number4},
...
and at the end from {{date1,number1},..{dateN,numberN}} get prediction {dateN+1,numberN+1}

Comment: Also, which net have you used? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible using a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). For an intro to RNN in Mathematica take a look at [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=105&disp=list&v=1839)

Comment: Hello Rohit. I tried your example with simple NN just replaced data with
data = {{2018, 05, 23, 440} -> {2018, 06, 13, 451}, {2018, 06, 13, 
    451} -> {2018, 06, 25, 442}, {2018, 06, 25, 442} -> {2018, 07, 11,
     442}, {2018, 07, 11, 442} -> {2018, 07, 25, 441}, {2018, 07, 25, 
    441} -> {2018, 08, 8, 440}, {2018, 08, 8, 440} -> {2018, 08, 22, 
    440}, {2018, 08, 22, 440} -> {2018, 09, 5, 440}, {2018, 09, 5, 
    440} -> {2018, 09, 19, 441}, {2018, 09, 19, 441} -> {2018, 10, 3, 
    445}, {2018, 10, 3, 445} -> {2018, 10, 15, 440}}

Comment: The net kind predict the reasonable next element, but it is not quite accurate. For example, trained[{2018, 10, 3, 445}] // Round returns {2018, 10, 14, 441} instead of explicitely given in the data  {2018, 10, 15, 440}. 
How is it possible to improve network training? I realized that the loss never goes below 2.6, while on your data in drops down to 10^-2. Could more training data or change in some options fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: You should not expect a model to exactly reproduce training data. If it did it would be overfitting, which is bad. See [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-165e6942b229) to learn more about bias and variance. Also in the toy example above there are very few training samples, so it is not surprising that it does not perform well. I might be able to help more if you can share exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you, Rohit. Do you have an estimate what number of training samples I would need to improve the training? I.e. your example is pretty similar, but the net seems to predict much better.